# Extention like system for a Zend Framework project

Tags: zend-framework

I´m working on a personal project, i´m building my own CMS, primarily for learning purposes,
but trying to come up with a solid system that can continusly expand. So for that i like to have a extensions like system, so new extensions can be created and managed, each having custom settings and so on.

What would be the best way to accomplish   something like this using Zend Framework, using Zend plugins system? resources? i´m just started working with zend framework, so some ideas would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to do it.  Zend's plugin system, isn't really a plugin system.  You can add things to the library and make them accessible in various ways, but there's nothing like what Wordpress has for plugins or extensions.

I think (if you really want to reinvent the wheel), you're better off making your own API within the application (with function calls and extensible helper classes).  Otherwise every plugin will be something like an action or view helper.

Another option would be to jump on the ZF 2 boat and take a look at ZF 2 modules.

Comment: Not trying to abuse, but can you give me a idea on how to build this extensions system? just to point me in the right direction...